# How do you mock a ContentResolver for Android 33?

Tags: android, mocking, android-contentprovider, android-testing, android-contentresolver

I want to make sure that the below method only returns what it is supposed to by writing a test for it.

```kotlin
internal fun getMusicFromMediaStore(contentResolver: ContentResolver): List<MusicFile>
```

The problem I am facing is that every thing I have found explaining how to do this so far is way out of date.

I start here in the official documentation for Android,
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/content-providers, and a note says "Note: This document focuses on ProviderTestCase2 which is being replaced by the experimental ProviderTestRule." That note links to this, https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/provider/ProviderTestRule, which says "This class is deprecated ... relies on deprecated android.test.mock. Consider using a real provider, or implementing a fake ContentProvider specific to your use case."

I ended up trying to use the provider provided by Mokito 4.1.0, but the code I wrote does not work correctly. This is how I populate the ContentResolver with entries.

```kotlin
    /**
     * Inserts music into the ContentResolver;
     * it is specifically the MediaStore's audio database that is populated.
     * 
     * @param id The id of the row in the MediaStore.
     * @param displayName The display name row in the MediaStore.
     * @param isMusic True if the MediaStore entry is to be considered music.
     */
    private fun insert(id: Long, displayName: String, isMusic: Int) {
        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, id)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName)
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, isMusic)
        val app = RuntimeEnvironment.getApplication()
        app.contentResolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            contentValues
        )
    }
```

It is supposed to return a non-empty cursor here, but it does not

```kotlin
            // The query parameters
            val projection = arrayOf(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC
            )
            val selection = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC} != ?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf("0")
            val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"

            // The cursor that is empty
            contentResolver.query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                sortOrder
            )
```

Comment: I ended up using a dedicated device with a preloaded MediaStore to perform the test.